# Photo viewer with full screen support and system-wide shortcuts capable

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I want to show pictures on a videoprojector (in full screen via extended screen) while i continue to work on the main screen.

Integrated photo viewer of Windows can show pictures fullscreen on the second screen (with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>) but the problem is in this mode, the main screen become black and you cannot continue to work in another program.

So i search a photo viewer with these 2 functions:

- allow full screen projection on a second screen while the main screen remain available
- This program must capture specific keys at system-wide level (example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) to show the next /previous picture/close viewer, permitting to continue working on other program on the main screen

Do you know such a program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, i've found a solution that works. I use XNView (but others can do the job) that have a good full screen mode.

Plus, i use HotKeyP (https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotkeyp/) that permit to map a particular keystroke to send an action to another window from anywhere.

For example, to ask to xnview to go to the next photo, you can set this action:
[image]

Here, 43 is the command number to send. For previous photo, 44. For closing XNView it's 28.

HotKeyP is packaged with an handful tool called spy.exe to snif actions in all window.